# Does the word 'never' go with 'as well'?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> Say - I never do it. He ***never*** does it ***as well.***

I am not comfortable using 'never' with 'as well'. While 'as well' means 'also', in most of the negative sentences, I think 'also' fits better over 'as well'. Because I think 'as well' has a little hint of 'positivity'. So, in above sentence, 'He also never does it' seems better. Am I right?

Thank You.

Comment: cannot explain, but I think, 'never' with 'as well' does not go well. :(

Comment: Right, these are polarity items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As well** and **also** both generally have a **positive** or additive connotation... along with **too**.

It is natural to use them in sentences that are positive/additive:

> I bought my ticket to the movie. He got his **as well**.
>
> I like my car. My spouse likes it **also**.

In the case of a **negative** phrase, or one that subtracts, the better choice would be:

> I don't smoke. He **never** smokes **either**.
>
> I don't have a car.  He doesn't **either**.

**As well** can also imply quality, which wouldn't be much of an issue here, but just a warning.

> I got an A on my test. He never does **as well** [as I do].

In this case it means that he never gets the same grade or better.

Comment: So, in the context of my sentence, 'never' does not fit with 'as well', isn't it? And I am not talking about the phrase 'as well as'.

Comment: That's right, 'as well' is not the correct choice of words to go with 'never' in this context.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect two negative ideas, you don't use as well, also, or too. Instead, you use either. So the correct sentences are as follows:

I never do it. He never does it either.

It's incorrect grammatically if you say "I never do it. [As well] he [also] never does it".

Comment: Upvote.  The right answer, but not quite explained. Hope my edit conveys your intent.